# What tooltip does jquery.com use?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

Visit http://jquery.com/ and hover over Lightweight Footprint, CSS3 Compliant or Cross-browser. I want that, but searching through source code I can't find anything specific. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a custom one with custom CSS as well.

The code is defined here:

http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/scripts/custom.js

and here:

http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/css/screen.css

Look for `jq-checkpointSubhead` for the corresponding part.

Comment: Cool. And can I use it in my projects?

Comment: There are no copyright info, so I would say you can learn from it but no direct usage is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

A GREAT Tooltip option is QTip.  I've used the betas of the JQuery UI tips, as well as several others, but Qtip always seems to winout, hands down.  The developers of QTip appear to be working with the Jquery UI team to introduce similar functionality into a future release of UI, so stay tuned....

Extra bonus that Qtip is the only tip plugin I've found so far that's 100% themeroller compliant.

Comment: It doesn't work for me (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938402/what-is-wrong-with-my-qtip-code)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a specific tooltip plugin.

The relevant javascript:

```
$('#jq-intro li').hover(
  function(){$(this).find('div.jq-checkpointSubhead:hidden').fadeIn(500);},
  function(){$(this).find('div.jq-checkpointSubhead:visible').fadeOut(500);}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a tooltip plugin [check out jQueryTools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html).

[Here's a list](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/) of a bunch of different ones.